# Move <DIV> to center of page on Hover using CSS only

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for some help in trying to get DIVs to move to the center of my page when the mouse hovers over it.  I'd like to do this only with CSS.

Right now my CSS looks like this:

```
.cards {
  /* max-width: 1920px; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 500px));
}

.card {
  background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 1rem;
  /* height: 4rem; */
  border: 2px solid rgb(64, 64, 64);
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform ease-in-out 0.9s;
}

.card:hover {
  /* transform: scale(2) translateX(calc(90% / 2)) translateY(calc(90% / 2)); */
  transform: scale(1.2);
  z-index: 20;
}
```

So basically my CSS can zoom in my DIVs but only does this at the location they're at.  I tried Translate (as commented in my CSS), but it will only push to the right and down and at a set distance.  If the DIV is in the bottom-right corner of my page, this pushes it out of frame.  What can I do to center it no matter where on the page the DIV is located?

[EDIT]
Request for full code was asked, so I posted it here:
https://codepen.io/superbartimus/pen/QWqxgYo

Comment: can you also post your html code?

Comment: You'd have to pop it out of the grid using position I suspect, or completely alter your grid structure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+OR+CSS+center+div+hover+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I added full HTML / CSS code to the post... linking to here: https://codepen.io/superbartimus/pen/QWqxgYo